# node js self this call method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on NodeJS and I have this module:
Manager.js
with this code (this is not all the code...):

```
 //
// Object Manager
function Manager(params) {

    client = new ModbusRTU();

  }

  //connessione alla seriale per lettura modbus
Manager.prototype.connectClient = function(){


    // try to connect
     client.connectRTUBuffered ("/dev/ttyS3", { baudRate: 19200 })
      .then(function()
     {
        mbsState  = MBS_STATE_GOOD_CONNECT;
        mbsStatus = "Connected, wait for reading...";
        console.log(mbsStatus);
     })
     .catch(function(e)
     {
        mbsState  = MBS_STATE_FAIL_CONNECT;
        mbsStatus = e.message;
        console.log("Error:"+e);
     });
     client.setTimeout (20);
}

//read data
Manager.prototype.readData = function(){

    var self = this;
    client.setID(2);
    // try to read data
    client.readCoils (0, 7, function(error,data){
        if(!error){


             self.checkEmergency();
         }

   });


 }
 //emergency
 Manager.prototype.checkEmergency= function(){



}
exports.Manager=Manager;
```

client part of code is about a modbus application. 
When I try to call "self.checkEmergency()" from readData, I have this error:

```
 "self.checkEmergency() is not a function"
```

Why? 
The method readData is called inside a method like this:

```
 Manager.prototype.caller= function(){

    var self = this;
    self.readData();

 }
```

I also have used self to pass the object to the callback...
Any idea?

Comment: How is `readData()` getting called, as that will tell if you are using the correct `this`

Comment: Now i edit the post

Comment: You might enjoy learning how to use arrow functions that retain the local, lexical value of `this` so you can get rid of all the `var self = this;` statements entirely and just use `this`.

Comment: Yeah I agree with @jfriend00 and #patrick-events, just go follow the call stack and see who is changing the scope and to avoid it could be good to use arrow functions () => {}.

Comment: The code you show does not appear to be code that would cause this problem.  You show `self.readData()`.  If `self` was not correct there, then you would get an error on that call.  So, we can assume that `this` is correct when you enter `readData()` and you then assign it with `self = this` and then call `self.checkEmergency()`.  So, it appears that `self` is the desired value.  My guess is that there is more code you are not showing us that is affecting the problem.